# Interrupting process in Qt to update GUI

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, python-2.4

I am using Python 2.4.3 and Qt Designer to make a GUI.  When I press one of my buttons it goes off and does several serial processes.  After each process I want to update the user by outputting text to the GUI, however, that text doesn't come out until I have completed all my processes.  I have seen other questions regarding this same issue where processEvents() is recommended.  Dumb question, what module do I have to import to get the processEvents() function that will make this work or is there one for Python 2.4.3?  I am running on a Red Hat Linux machine.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The serial processes should be done in another thread; `processEvents()` is a work-around in this case.

Comment: you would be better off splitting each process up and having them trigger each other through slots so the event loop can run in between, or using another thread that signals the gui thread

Comment: Ratchet Freak - I like that idea.  I just tried it but I couldn't figure out how to connect slots together; so I created 3 slots and triggered them all to occur when the run button was pressed.  Luckely it ran all three in the order they are listed in the QT Designer.  However, it didn't update the GUI until after the last one was finished, so it didn't work. So I guess I still need to know how to start a slot once another one has finished.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in C++, then this answer is not ready-to-use, but I solved my similar problem crafting a small helper to be called from the loop

```
#include <QTimer>
#include <QEventLoop>

inline void do_events(int delay = 1) {
    QEventLoop lp;
    QTimer::singleShot(delay, &lp, SLOT(quit()));
    lp.exec();
}
```

this allows Qt to process its events. Its name is dangerously nostalgic of VB times...

Answer (score 0):

`Qt.qApp` or `QApplication.instance()` yields the `QApplication` object which has a `processEvents` that you can call.

Comment: THANKS,  That works.  I put an 'import qt' at the top of the routine and then put in 'qt.qApp.processEvents()' after each of my items I wanted to print.

Comment: @user3005501: Glad it helped! Here on Stack Overflow we expect you to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem, and up-vote answers you think are helpful and informative.